# Which is uniform at steady state: flux or flow rate?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, heat-conduction, transport-phenomena, steady-state

**Background**

My initial focus was on heat transport, but I tried to gain insight by working with the analogous mass transport equations and I realized my confusion isn't necessary specific to heat transport.

Here's the differential form of the [general continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation) for any property $Q$ being accumulated, transported and generated (respectively terms in equation) at any point in space and time:

$ \frac{\partial \rho_Q}{\partial t} = -\nabla \cdot \vec{j}_Q + G_Q $.

Let's take $Q$ to be thermal energy (colloquially "heat", despite inconsistency with the thermodynamic definition). The heat density may be considered $\rho_Q = \frac{Q}{V} = \frac{mc(T-T_0)}{V} = \rho c \Delta T $. The heat flux can be given by Fourier's Law, $ \vec{j}_Q = \vec{\phi} \equiv \frac{\partial \vec{q}}{\partial A} = -k\nabla T$ (with $q \equiv \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}$ as the heat transfer rate). (Substituting these into the continuity equation derives the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation).) Let's disregard generation ($G_Q=0$).

At steady state, heat does not accumulate or deplete within the system, thus $ \frac{\partial \rho_Q}{\partial t} = 0 $ (1).

Note that means $ \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = 0 $ (2) for all points in space.

By (1) (and disregarding generation) the continuity equation becomes $ \nabla \cdot \vec{\phi} = 0 $ (3) or $\oiint \vec{\phi} \cdot d \vec{A} = 0$ (4) in integral form.

There is no net heat transfer, but heat can still cross the boundary obeying $ q_{in} = q_{out} $ (5), where $q_{\text{thru } S} = \iint_S \vec{\phi} \cdot d \vec{A}$ for any surface $S$.

Equations 1-5 are all conditions I've seen claimed true at steady state, and I believe I'm comfortable with them.

**Uncertainty**

My professor asserts that at steady state, for 1 dimensional heat flow*, the heat flux is uniform in space. Since "heat flux" is often used to refer to both $ \vec{\phi} \equiv \frac{\partial \vec{q}}{\partial A} $ and $q \equiv \frac{\partial Q_{\text{thru } S}}{\partial t} = \iint_S \vec{\phi} \cdot d \vec{A}$, I'm not sure whether $ \frac{d\phi}{dx} = 0$ or $ \frac{dq}{dx} = 0$ (the *flux* or the *flow rate* is constant through the flow direction). For uniform area, apparently both are true, but I'd like to know which is more fundamental.

*The situations we've considered so far are heat flowing perpendicularly through layers of finite thickness (with a heat source or constant temperature across the entire surface of the layer), and a ball with heat flowing radially and isotropically. I'm trying to build a more general understanding.

Likewise, I've seen it claimed (online, I'll try to find the link) in general the "flux" is not spatially constant because the surface might not be uniform and $A$ might vary. This could mean $ \frac{d\phi}{dx} \neq 0$ or $ \frac{dq}{dx} \neq 0$ when the cross-section is non-uniform. I'm not sure which is the case.

The analogy to mass transport would be: for an incompressible fluid flowing at steady state in direction $x$ through a pipe of possibly varying cross-section, which is true: $ \frac{d \dot{m}}{dx} = 0$ or $ \frac{d v_x}{dx} = 0$? I am aware that at steady state $ \nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0$, but I'm not sure that implies $ \frac{d v_x}{dx} = 0$ for axial flow. I'm also aware that at steady state $ \dot{m}_{in} = \dot{m}_{out} $, but I don't see how that can rigorously prove $ \frac{d \dot{m}}{dx} = 0$.

**Question**

For axial heat flow through a conductor of varying cross-section at steady state, is $ \frac{d\phi}{dx} = 0$ or $ \frac{dq}{dx} = 0$ true, and how is it derived? I am also interested in what the condition is for the more general 3D case, if it is appropriate to include that.

Comment: Please try editing your question to ask one question at a time. If you are referencing claims from elsewhere, please provide citations so that the reader can understand the context and assumptions. Example: a rod with a different diameter at either end can be analyzed as a "1D" heat transfer problem, but there is some conduction in the radial direction, which is an additional dimension. Thus, "ID" can be ambiguous. Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The source of the claims is my professor. I'm not not if it's appropriate to split up the questions, they are all about what conditions are true of thermal conduction at steady state, and I'd be posting three separate questions with the same background. Thanks for your points about the ambiguity of 1D, I'll edit.

Comment: In the example of the rod with the changing cross-sectional area, some heat moves radially, so while conservation of energy dictates that $\nabla\cdot\vec\phi=0$, the flux $\phi$ isn't constant down the rod: $\frac{d\phi}{dx}\neq 0$ (because of conservation of energy, the flux is greater where the rod is narrower). Does that not address that section of your question?

Comment: @Chemomechanics It does, thank you. But how can we say $\frac{dq}{dx} = \frac{d(\phi A)}{dx} =0$? I'm struggling to see the connection mathematically.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the auxiliary questions and improve the organization and focus.

Comment: Try drawing a differential slice of the conductor and applying conservation of energy to the incoming $q(x)$ and outgoing $q(x+dx)$. They must be equal, so $q$ must not vary with $x$. But if $A$ varies with $x$, then generally $\phi$ must also. In the 3D analysis, we find that there must be some  heat flow in the $y$ and $z$ directions; otherwise, we’d see flow through the slanted surface. The combined heat flow in 3D ensures a divergence of zero at any point.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I had tried that, but I see now I made a mistake. Your description was very helpful, thank you!